# JFrog Artifactory OSS: UI service unavailable, "Trying to connect an http1.x server"

Tags: frontend, artifactory

I'm trying to set up a new JFrog Artifactoy OSS server on a Windows 10 machine.

While it actually seems to be up and running the UI is not working. When trying to open `http://localhost:8082/ui/` I just get a "Service unavailable" error.

In the /var/log/frontend-service.log I see the following error:

`[main                ] - Couldn't register on Router, retry number: 120, Error : [Trying to connect an http1.x server]`

I couldn't find any errors in the other logs.

I already made some desperate attempts in my system.yaml like setting the IP manually, tested setting a proxy, etc. But no luck. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you did not see any error in router-service.log? Also please check catalina logs as well.

Comment: Hi, both seem fine. The router-service.log even tells me "Router (jfrou) service initialization completed in 21.888 seconds. Listening on port: 8082". Very strange, I'm now trying to increase the log level to dig deeper.

Comment: can you check frontend-service.log also please send the `system.yaml` you may have.

Comment: @DocT: How did you resolve this issue?? I am currently facing the same type of issue where the "systemctl status artifactory" reports the artifactory to be working fine but "telnet IP 8082" states CONNECTION REFUSED error.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was downgrading to 7.2. In all newer versions (up to 7.7) I got this error but never quite found out why.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, I solved it by exposing port 8082 as well:

```
docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with version 7.7.3 and I just reverted to an older version I had 7.5.7 and it worked fine for me.